# Which projects have been ported successfully from Haskell to Frege?

Tags: haskell, porting, frege

I'd like to learn how to port Haskell code to Frege. Are there any projects that have already been ported and serve as good examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all of the existing library code (i.e. Prelude, Data, etc.) have been ported. Also things like QuickCheck, with almost no adaptions.

An interesting case is `Data.HashMap` which has the same interface as in Haskell, but the implementation relies on Java arrays.

Things to watch out for: unsupported GHC extensions, Strings/Text, code that uses foreign functions (that is, C).

In such cases the Frege analogue of Haskell is usually slightly different, or misses features. Examples would be JSON support and parser combinator libraries (Data.MicroParsec).